# Is there a word for people who directly report to me in office?

Tags: single-word-requests

There are about 10-12 co-workers who directly report to me in office. It's a private company but of very large size.

They are Junior to me in terms of experience and also are below me in Organisation hierarchy.  Also I am their manager/boss who is responsible for their annual appraisals in company.

I need to refer those people in many meetings and emails. I generally tend to use word "subordinate" to refer them, but I am not sure if that is the right word to use.

I am not sure "reportee" is valid English word.

Is there a word to for people who directly reports to me in office?

Comment: Well, in the US folks who directly report to you would be "direct reports".  Dunno what you mean by "in office", however.

Comment: thanks @HotLicks "direct reports" sound like 2 words and yes I hear people using that often in USA and Europe  during my interaction with them. "in office" means that these folks are my direct reports only "in office". When they go Onsite or out duty at client location, they report to different boss/manager during their stay at on site.

Comment: You had it:  they are your ***direct reports***

Comment: _Reportee_ is definitely not what you’re looking for. Apart from being a bit of a nonce word (though regularly formed, it’s not made its way into most dictionaries), it would mean ‘someone who has been reported’.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Report is the common word used in this context.

See the 4th definition under noun, in [OLD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/report):

***Report***

> An employee who reports to another employee.

Although they are your subordinates by your own description, the word subordinate carries with it the very clear sense that these people are lower in the company hierarchy than you. 
It would usually be used if there was a need to put emphasis on that detail. For example: "You need to get your subordinates to start doing their job!".

However, if you simply want a word to refer to people that you manage (directly or indirectly), the word report is the usual choice.

If the individual(s) report to you directly you could further qualify the relationship, by using the phrase:

***Direct report(s)*** ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/direct-report))

> An employee whose position at work is directly below that of another
>   person, and who is managed by that person:
>
> She has a dozen direct reports, but manages many more people.

If one of your direct reports manages four people, those four individuals are your reports but not your direct reports.

Comment: Report/Direct report is not used in British English, where "report" is chiefly a written account of an event or circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

I would use "my staff" to refer to all the people reporting to me in the organisation hierarchy.

See the OED definition (22):

> **a.** *gen.* A body of persons employed, under the direction of a manager or chief, in the work of an establishment or the execution of some undertaking (e.g. a newspaper, hospital, government survey, school, etc.).

and

> **c** *spec.* in a business organization:  (a) the employees responsible for providing advisory and ancillary services to line managers and their subordinates;

Comment: I call them my minions

Comment: I don't recommend "direct reports" to describe your subordinates or staff.   By the way, "in office" generally refers to someone who has been elected or otherwise chosen for a particular position.  "The president's term in office is 4 years"; "The cabinet member was in office for three years, but resigned due to illness."   I think your first sentence would be better if you say "...10-12 co-workers in my office who report to me."

Comment: “My staff” will also include any employees who are below you in the organisational hierarchy, but who don’t report directly to you. If you’re the CEO, everyone in the company is ‘your staff’, but most likely only a few upper-level managers report directly to you.